# Creating a deck of cards in c#

Tags: c#

So I'm trying to create a deck of cards for one of my programming classes. I've never really done anything like this so sorry if I made some stupid mistake. I'm coding this in Visual Studio (per class rules). I am trying to create an array of Card objects for my Deck. The problem I am getting is that when I try and print the array out all I get is 52 lines of Card_Games.Card (the namespace is Card_Games). What did I do wrong in my Card class to not properly assign the value and suit of a card to that Card object?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Deck.FillDeck();
        Deck.PrintDeck();
    }
}

class Card
{
    public int Value;
    public static string[] SuitsArray = new string[] {"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"};
    public string Suit;

    public Card(int value, string suit)
    {
        Value = value;
        Suit = suit;
    }

    public Card(string input)
    {
        string tempValue = "";
        string suitSentence = "";
        switch (Value)
        {
            case 11:
                tempValue = "Jack";
                break;
            case 12:
                tempValue = "Queen";
                break;
            case 13:
                tempValue = "King";
                break;
            case 14:
                tempValue = "Ace";
                break;
            default:
                tempValue = Value.ToString();
                break;
        }
        switch (Suit)
        {
            case "Hearts":
                suitSentence = " of Hearts";
                break;
            case "Diamonds":
                suitSentence = " of Diamonds";
                break;
            case "Clubs":
                suitSentence = " of Clubs";
                break;
            case "Spades":
                suitSentence = " of Spades";
                break;
        }
        input = tempValue + suitSentence;
    }
}

class Deck
{
    public static Object[] deck = new Object[52];


    public static void FillDeck()
    {
        int index = 0;
        foreach (string suit in Card.SuitsArray)
        {
            for (int value = 2; value <= 14; value++)
            {
                Card card = new Card(value, suit);
                deck[index] = card;
                index++;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void PrintDeck()
    {
        for (int i=0; i<52; i++)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(deck[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First and foremost, unless you implement `Card.ToString` (i.e. override the default implementation), you won't get a meaningful output, because .NET doesn't know how to convert a "card" into a `string`.

Comment: So I just need to do an override on the ToString method?

Comment: also, public Card(string input) doesn't actually appear to be doing anything

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: That's the first thing to do if you want to get a textual representation, yes. Other remarks would be: 1) if you are using `static` methods, you are usually doing something wrong. In this case, it means that only a single deck can exist in your app. 2) type of `deck` should be `Card[]` or `List<Card>`, not `Object[]`. 3) `public Card(string input)` is a constructor, which doesn't do anything.

Comment: if you rename public Card(string input) to your ToString override, then return the last line instead of assigning it to a throw away var, you should be most of the way there

Comment: So in my Card class I need to override ToString? What would I put in that method. Sorry I'm kinda of following but still don't quite understand.

Comment: Ok I'll try these tips. Thank you

Comment: Yes, change `public Card(string input)` into `public override ToString()` and return `tempValue + suitSentence` from that method.

Comment: Awesome changing that to an override worked to print out the correct strings. And @Groo thanks for that tip because I will have to create another deck as I will be making a blackjack game and blackjack uses four decks

Comment: Why is a deck a collection of objects, instead of a collection of cards? Do you intend to have a deck of numbers and giraffes or something?

Comment: @MattCV27, great, you took my idea for teaching myself C#. I was looking for syntax on how to print out a list of cards when I found this post.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a slightly optimized version.

I've added getters to pull a Named Value and a full Name, e.g "Ace Of Spades". And used an `Enum` for suites.

Then I've used a single loop with the modulo operator (`%`) and `Math.Floor` to populate the deck. This is where the enum comes into play as it is trivial to work with enums and ints.

```
public class Card
{
    public enum Suites
    {
        Hearts = 0,
        Diamonds,
        Clubs,
        Spades
    }

    public int Value
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public Suites Suite
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    //Used to get full name, also useful 
    //if you want to just get the named value
    public string NamedValue
    {
        get
        {
            string name = string.Empty;
            switch (Value)
            {
                case (14):
                    name = "Ace";
                    break;
                case (13):
                    name = "King";
                    break;
                case (12):
                    name = "Queen";
                    break;
                case (11):
                    name = "Jack";
                    break;
                default:
                    name = Value.ToString();
                    break;
            }

            return name;
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return NamedValue + " of  " + Suite.ToString();
        }
    }

    public Card(int Value, Suites Suite)
    {
        this.Value = Value;
        this.Suite = Suite;
    }
}

public class Deck
{
    public List<Card> Cards = new List<Card>();
    public void FillDeck()
    {
        public void FillDeck()
        {
          //Can use a single loop utilising the mod operator % and Math.Floor
          //Using divition based on 13 cards in a suited
          for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
          {
             Card.Suites suite = (Card.Suites)(Math.Floor((decimal)i/13));
             //Add 2 to value as a cards start a 2
             int val = i%13 + 2;
             Cards.Add(new Card(val, suite));
          }
         }
    }

    public void PrintDeck()
    {
        foreach(Card card in this.Cards)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(card.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Xuj7b6

Comment: Bingo! Thanks Jon, this `List<Card>` is exactly what I was looking for. Definitely an optimized version.

Comment: There is still a lot I don't understand like why `public List<Card> Cards = new List<Card>();` instead of just `public List<Card> cards;`? And why not add a constructor function of `public Deck {}` inside of the `Deck` class?

Comment: @Daniel `public List<Card> Cards = new List<Card>();` is force of habit, I prefer to have an empty list instead of a `null` object, no `null reference exceptions` that way. As for the constructor, when answering a question, I try not to change the original code too much so the OP doesn't get overwhelmed with radical changes, but yes in the real world I'd probably replace  `FillDeck` with a constructor.

Comment: @JonP, very nice answer, though in my humble opinion, it seems we don't need `(Math.Floor((decimal)i/13))` part, since it seems division between 2 integer values i.e. ( i and 13 ) will always result in 1 integer value. So it seems `Card.Suites suite = ( Card.Suites ) i / 13;` will do.

Comment: @nIcEcOw fair point. I may have been dealing with jumping between C# and javascript a lot at that point with javascript being loosely typed you need to floor.

Answer (score 1):

Change `object[]` to `Card[]`. Then in your print method you can print `deck[i].Value` and `deck[i].Suit`. Here it is as a console app:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Deck.FillDeck();
        Deck.PrintDeck();
        Console.ReadLine(); 
    }
}

class Card
{
    public int Value;
    public static string[] SuitsArray = new string[] { "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades" };
    public string Suit;

    public Card(int value, string suit)
    {
        Value = value;
        Suit = suit;
    }

    public Card(string input)
    {
        string tempValue = "";
        string suitSentence = "";
        switch (Value)
        {
            case 11:
                tempValue = "Jack";
                break;
            case 12:
                tempValue = "Queen";
                break;
            case 13:
                tempValue = "King";
                break;
            case 14:
                tempValue = "Ace";
                break;
            default:
                tempValue = Value.ToString();
                break;
        }
        switch (Suit)
        {
            case "Hearts":
                suitSentence = " of Hearts";
                break;
            case "Diamonds":
                suitSentence = " of Diamonds";
                break;
            case "Clubs":
                suitSentence = " of Clubs";
                break;
            case "Spades":
                suitSentence = " of Spades";
                break;
        }
        input = tempValue + suitSentence;
    }
}

class Deck
{
    public static Card[] deck = new Card[52];


    public static void FillDeck()
    {
        int index = 0;
        foreach (string suit in Card.SuitsArray)
        {
            for (int value = 2; value <= 14; value++)
            {
                Card card = new Card(value, suit);
                deck[index] = card;
                index++;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void PrintDeck()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{deck[i].Value} {deck[i].Suit}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you meant to say `Card[]` and not `Deck[]`, right?